# Request in flask API deployed in Cloud Run doesn't work

Tags: flask, post, request, google-cloud-run

I have an application in Flask that should receive an image per POST request. The request works with the server running locally, but it does not work on my API implemented by Cloud Run :(

I would appreciate any pointers!

Regards, Helena.

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def predict():

    # initialize the data dictionary that will be returned from the view
    data = {"success": False}

    # ensure an image was properly uploaded to our endpoint
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':

        _file = flask.request.files['image']

        if _file:

            # read the image in PIL format
            thermal_image = flask.request.files['image'].read()

            # get thermal region on embedded image
            try:
                image = get_cropped_embedded(thermal_image)
                #print(image)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                data = {"Success": 'Be positive!'}
                return flask.jsonify(data)

################ More code

            data.update({
                    "path": path,
                    "success": True
                })
            
            else:

                logging.info("No hot point found out. Exitting without classification.")

                return flask.jsonify(data)

    # return the data dictionary as a JSON response
    return flask.jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kV3v.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50IUn.png)

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by not working? 
Are you seeing any error message? Can you see something in the logs?

Comment: @JoseV, I've updated now. The API understands that a POST request has occurred but it stops at this part and returns false.